# Add conditional options to a javascript command

Tags: javascript, node.js

My current code is working and looks like

```
if (Number.isInteger(number)) {
    ffmpeg(video.mp4)

        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Screenshots taken');
        })

        .screenshots({
            count: number,
            folder: screenshotsOutput,
            size: '1024x700'
        })
} else {
    ffmpeg(video.mp4)

        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Screenshots taken');
        })

        .screenshots({
            timestamps: number,
            folder: screenshotsOutput,
            size: '1024x700'
        })
}
```

number could be an array or an integer. If its an array, the parameter count should be provided. If its an array, it should be used in the parameter timestamps. My code is working but I was wondering if it's possible to optimize it. I tried this but this is not working:

```
ffmpeg(video.mp4)

    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Screenshots taken');
    })

    .screenshots({
        count: Number.isInteger(number) && number,
        folder: screenshotsOutput,
        size: '1024x700'
        timestamps: Array.isArray(number) && number
    })
```

Will it also be possible to do something like this

Beside this, I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this (I know that it dose not work as I write it) or shall I rewrite the whole command if I want to add/delete an option in the command

```
ffmpeg(video.mp4)

    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Screenshots taken');
    })
// Check if sccreenshots are needed
if (withScreenshots) {
.screenshots({
        count: Number.isInteger(number) && number,
        folder: screenshotsOutput,
        size: '1024x700'
timestamps: Array.isArray(number) && number
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, to shorten your code you can use ternary/conditional operator inside the key expression:

```
{
    key: value,
    [expression]: value
}
```

So for you it's something like:

```
{
    key: value,
    [condition ? "key1" : "key2"]: value
}
```

As for the second example, it's also possible but for you it doesn't work because you're not calling `screenshots` method on anything.

You need to save the return value of `ffmpeg` to use later:

```
const thing = func(args)
                .on("event", doStuff); // `.on` returns the event listener itself,
                                       // that allows chaining calls to it

if(condition) thing.on("anotherEvent", doSomethingElse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do you well:

```
{
  folder: screenshotsOutput,
  size: '1024,700',
  ...(Number.isInteger(number) 
      ? {count: number} 
      : Array.isArray(number) ? {timestamps: number} : {}
     )
}
```